# Pandas: If three columns have same entries then merge the 4th column(which is integer) and show count in 5th column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a datafame which will look like this: where col4 has unique ID. There are posts on concatenating strings, but I have to concatenate integer which is throwing error if I am using str(int) which is not the usual case

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | ABC | ggg | 1 | kogyk |
| 1999 | ABC | ggg | 2 | hfu |
| 1989 | CAT | ppp | 3 | gl |
| 1999 | ABC | uyt | 4 | klyif |
| 1989 | CAT | ppp | 5 | gil |

I want to merge the contents of col4 if col1,col2,col3 values match and add a count of it. output must look like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1999 | ABC | ggg | 1,2 | 2 |
| 1989 | CAT | ppp | 3,5 | 2 |
| 1999 | ABC | uyt | 4 | 1 |

I got the necessary output with:
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).agg(col4=('col4', lambda x: ','.join([str(x) for x in list(x))), count=('col4', 'size')).reset_index() works as expected

Comment: The last row of sample output should be: |1999|ABC|uyt|ID4|1|

Comment: try: ```df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).agg(col4=('col4', list), count=('col4', 'size')).reset_index()```

Comment: 'col1' - is the error message @khaled koubaa

Comment: copy paste the full error here

Comment: It worked! I had misplaced brackets. Thank you. is it is possible to have it as a comma seperated ID rather than list? @khaled koubaa

Comment: yes, I will send you how, meanwhile, please upvote my comment since the solution works

Comment: ```df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).agg(col4=('col4', lambda x: ','.join(list(x))), count=('col4', 'size')).reset_index()```

Comment: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found - is the error message

Comment: df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).agg(col4=('col4', lambda x: ','.join([str(x) for x in list(x))), count=('col4', 'size')).reset_index() works as expected

Comment: ok good, if you need more assistance, let me know